# Confused about while check

Tags: c++, string, input, iostream, cin

I'm confused about this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    string name_one;
    string name_two;
    string name_three;    

    cout << "Please enter a name: ";
    cin >> name_one;
    cout << "\nReading data...";

    while (name_one.empty())
    {
        cout << "\nFailed!";
        cout << "Please enter a name: ";
        cin >> name_one;
        cout << "\nReading data...";
    }

    cout << "Completed!\n";

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

It is very easy, but when I debug it and for example I don't write anything but just press Enter, it doesn't do anything. Just keeps showing me a flashing underscore under the line, and if I keep pressing Enter it just jumps line by line. Why does the program not read the condition? What I want is that if the user doesn't write anything, the condition in the `while` starts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a stream extractor, `>>`, which is a *formatted input function.* For many types (such as fundamental types and `std::string`), these start by skipping all whitespace currently in the stream<sup>(1)</sup>, then extracting characters as long as these are a valid representation of the data type you want to extract.

In other words, when you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on standard input, there will only be a newline character in the stream. A newline is whitespace, so the `>>` function is still stuck inside its "skip starting whitespace" mode. Only when you enter a non-whitespace character will the second part ("extract characters and try to interpret them as a representation of the extracted type") kick in.

If you want to always read by lines, you can use the [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) stream function, or the [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function. You can also combine these with an [`istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) object for parsing the line.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> This behaviour can be controlled by the stream manipulators [`skipws` and `noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws), or directly by the stream's [formatting flags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags).